# Scrape 2000+ html site and import into WP using a Divi theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm looking to import a massive amount of HTML pages into a WP site. Because of the massive amount I would like to automate the process as much as possible. The site contains mostly text and img.
Which tools are the best choice for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I would divide this task into couple steps:

1. Group content(html pages) into logic groups, maybe some of theme should have different authors
2. Analyze html, find wrappers, etc, where content is stored
3. custom coding part, scrape html with some scripts, maybe a php one into wordpress xml import file(s) i suggest to divide such huge amount into couple xml files.
4. import via wordpress import tool
   [Simple WordPress Import Structure XML Example](https://gist.github.com/iwek/3977831)

Or you can try such plugin: [HTML Import 2](https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-html-pages/)

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario i would recommend you to use wp-importer plugin of wordpress its very use full for things like that.

The WordPress Importer will import the following content from a WordPress export file

Posts, pages and other custom post types, images, Comments ,Custom fields and post meta, also it can import Categories, tags and terms from custom taxonomies Authors

[link here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reaction, but as you can read the sites are plain HTML and not present in a WP site so i don't have the option to export them